# How to get TCustomUniDataSet from a TUniQuery in Delphi

Tags: delphi, devart

I have a TUniQuery in Delphi, using the DevArt component.

This works fine, and I can assign values using syntax like `qry1.Fields[1].AsString`.

But to avoid absolute indexing of database fields I would like to work with field names instead. After doing some research on forums, I found that the following works as well: `qry.fieldbyname('fieldname').AsString`.

Unfortunately, as [DevArt documentation states](https://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/?devart.unidac.tuniquery.htm) : "It publishes **most** of its inherited properties" (my enhancement). FieldByName is one of the unpublished properties.

In the code I can write `qry.parent.fieldbyname('fieldname').AsString` which works, but I would like to avoid what I see as a "hack".

So, as [TCustomUniDataSet](https://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/devart.unidac.tcustomunidataset.htm) is the parent of TUniQuery, how do I get to work with it, and the recordset of TQuery ?  Devart does recommend working with TUniquery, but what is then my way forward for non-published properties ?

> Applications should never use TCustomUniDataSet objects directly.
> Instead of TCustomUniDataSet, they should use TCustomUniDataSet
> descendants, such as TUniQuery and TUniTable, which inherit its
> dataset-related properties and methods.

Comment: Finding it hard to make sense of what you are asking. FieldByname works for TUniQuery (as seen in some of the examples in the getting started: https://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/basics.htm). What doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Brian it does work, but I do not have autocomplete i the IDE, probably because the property `FieldByName` exists, but is not published. So I have to remember that it's there. As the property IS published in parent, I can use  the `parent` reference, but I think there should be a better way ?